# Use exact match for apt install

Tags: apt, regex

I want to install `g++-9` but something like:

```
sudo apt install g++-9
```

Interprets `g++-9` as a regex (probably because there is no exact match as I don't have the toolchain PPA installed) and installs unrelated stuff like `python-clang-9`.

Can I tell apt to interpret this as a fixed string, or do I have to painfully try to escape the string as a regex?

Answer (score 0):

`apt search ^g\\+\\+-9$`

---

- `\\` decode as `\` in bash (ref: `man bash`)

> A non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character.

> \\     backslash

- `^` `$` `\` meaning (ref: `man 7 regex`)

> `^` (matching  the null string at the beginning of a line)

> `$` (matching the null string at the end of a line)

> a `\` followed by one of the characters "^.[$()|*+?{" (matching that character taken as an ordinary character)

Comment: To clarify, the question isn't how to install `g++-9`, it is how to prevent `apt` from interpreting `g++-9` as a regex.

Comment: I learn regex from https://ihateregex.io, try with regex expression `g\+\+-9` to match ```g++-11
gg+
g\+
g+\
g++--
g++12
g++-9
g++\
g+\+
```, only `g++-9` get matched.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I have tried it on both KDE Neon and Raspberry Pi.